# Mediawiki: passing advanced values to a #invoke?

Tags: lua, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, wikitext

The #invoke takes single values or key value pairs. Is there any way to get something like a key value pair to pass anything more than a single value?

For example, I would like a nested table to be passed, or just a pointer to a table defined in the same page?

`{{#invoke:scriptPath|myfunc|<some table?>|tableArg1=`***`???`***`|tableArg2=`***`???`***`}}`

I can't seem to figure out how this might be possible.

Perhaps I this might be possible with `#vardefine`? However I don't think these take anything more than a key value pair.

Perhaps my only option is to put jsonified data and have the func parse the json?

Any pointers would be appreciated.

*The #invoke is calling a Lua module*

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with tableArg1 and tableArg2? Are you constructing the table based on those? (That sounds like you could use a Mediawiki template, possibly.)

Comment: Ive got a lua module that accepts a nested lua table 
`inputTable`[`group`][`key`] => `value`
multiple [group] 
multiple [key]
values are just strings


see function `p.setColumnColorScale` here for reference [link](https://runescape.wiki/w/Module:Sandbox/User:Oo00oo00oO/conditionalWikiTable). Function `p.parseColorScaleOpts` has documentation for what the 2nd level to `inputTable` should look like

`inputTable = {};`
`inputTable['group1'] = { ["hello"]='0000ff', ["world"]='ff00ff', [1000]='00aaff'};`
`inputTable['group2'] = { ["0%"]='101010', ["%90%"]='ffffff'};`

Comment: Seems that JSON is the best option, unless there is only a limited number of posiible nested tables, in which case they can be loaded with `mw.loadData()` and only their identifiers be passed to `{{#invoke:}}`.

And forget about `{{#vardefine:}}`. Will stop working predictably soon.

Comment: So strange that yesterday there was [burninate request for wikimedia tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429530/burninate-wikimedia-or-donate-2-please-dont-scroll-past-this?cb=1), and today there is a question tagged with it. Is this **actually** about wikimedia or is it just a mistagging of mediawiki?

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/mw.Api.html these are things supported by wikimedia for extensions to a wiki site.